# Using elementary row operations to solve intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question I am struggling with is the following:
Solve the following using elementary row operations, and interpret each system of equations geometrically:
\begin{align*}
x - 3y + 2z &= 8\\
3x - 9y + 2z &= 4
\end{align*}
The answer given in the book is $x = -2+3t, y = t, z = 5$, and the planes meet in a line.

I put this in matrix form, so 
$$\left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}
1 & -3 & 2 & 8\\
3 & -9 & 2 & 4
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then I subtracted R1 from R2
$$\left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}
1 & -3 & 2 & 8\\
2 & -6 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then R1 - $\frac{1}{2}$R2
$$\left(\begin{array}{c c c|c}
0 & 0 & 2 & 10\\
-2 & -6 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right)
$$
So I got that $2z =10$, so $z = 5$, but I am stumped on how to continue. How can I get $x$ and $y$ and interpret the results in terms of plane intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Are you confused because you expect one result (one point in space)? If the result is a plane or line, there are infinitely many solutions.

Thus you need to introduce some new parameter - `t`. Depending on what you set `t` to it will point to different points in 3D space with coordinates:

```
x = 2 - 3t
y = t
z = 5
```

In order to get there, if you keep using vector notation, you first need to come up with a Particular Solution and the Null Space:

$$R=\left(\begin{array}{} 
2\\
0\\
5
\end{array}\right),
 N=\left(\begin{array}{}
-3\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

So the General Solution looks like this:

$$ 
\left(\begin{array}{} 
2\\
0\\
5
\end{array}\right)+t
\left(\begin{array}{}
-3\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Or you can keep working with polynomials and get to the result as described by @Matheus Andrade.

Answer (score 0):

$2z = 10$, so $z =  5$.

$2x - 6y = -4 \Rightarrow2x = -4 + 6y \Rightarrow x = -2 + 3y$. Let $y = t$, we get $x = -2 + 3t$, $y = t$, $z = 5$, as desired.